# Code for the expansion and contraction of the table view cell to display the text of a particular cell in iphone?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

Can any one give me the code for the  expansion and contraction of the table view cell to display the text of a particular cell in iphone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want variable heights for your table cells you will need to look into:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

But your question isn't clear enough to know for sure what you at trying to do.